# Purpose of verses in the Quran which humans do not understand?

Tags: quran, tafseer

Allah tells us in the Quran "And we have made the Quran easy for you to understand/learn" However there is another verse ([3:7](http://legacy.quran.com/3/7)) Allah tells us that no one knows the true meaning of the verse except Allah.
 The Quran is send down to teach mankind and jinns so why have verses where the meaning is hidden?
 Also there are many different ways a verse can be translated. I mean the literal meaning may not always be the same as the "tafseer" so how will people know what the real ruling is in the Quran?

There is even a hadith where the Prophet asks people what they thing a verse means and everyone gets it wrong as the real meaning is more like a riddle.

Comment: Could you please quote the hadith you mentioned?

Comment: Also remember that the verse 3:7 doesn't really mean that the sahaba didn't understand some verses which we don't understand today. Surely they did understand much more from it than we do today.

Answer (score 3):

The foundation of Allah's (ﷻ) Book is literal, as mentioned in the Qur'an itself. This is true of most of its verses. And they have been explained in detail by the Prophet (ﷺ), so there is no confusion. So when you ask, "the real ruling is in the Quran" - it is explained via the Sunnah. That is not hidden knowledge.

In addition to the literal verses, there are also *some* parables in the Qur'an. (Yes, the verse you referenced is speaking about parables). ►The wisdom behind parables is to make people contemplate and use their brains more deeply, as well as Him using them to guide/misguide with.

"Indeed, Allah is not timid to present an example - that of a mosquito or what is smaller than it. And those who have believed know that it is the truth from their Lord. But as for those who disbelieve, they say, "What did Allah intend by this as an example?" He misleads many thereby and guides many thereby. And He misleads not except the defiantly disobedient ~ Qur'an 2:26.

The Qur'an is described as the "Furqan" (criterion, ie distinguishes between truth and falsehood). Likewise, it distinguishes between the Believers and Disbelievers. The Believers read it and believe in it (and it heals their hearts). In contrast, the Unbelievers read it and question it/quarrel (and it increases them in anguish).

All of its verses are the truth from Allah (ﷻ). Easy to read/memorize/learn.

Answer (score -1):

There are two levels of Quran understanding. The first one is for all human and at this level Quran is very simple. Anyone who wants to get guidance from Quran can easily get with little effort. The other, the deep knowledge of Quran, its wisdom etc is too difficult and only the scholars have the ability to discuss such matter. 
In the End Allah knows and we don't.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could elaborate your answer by adding references to support your claims!