# How should I react to having doubts as a result of gaining knowledge about Islam?

Tags: doubts

I've been having some big doubts about Islam.

I have for less than 6 months been trying to establish prayers.  At the same time I thought it would be easier for me to maintain Salah while increasing my knowledge.

Before I got in searching for knowledge I was happy, with no doubts and actively praying in the fixed times; now I pray only Asr and Isha.  Even though I didn't had many much knowledge, I was sinful and happy about praying no matter my condition.

- I find so many prohibited things which should be outright avoided, and some of them seems to taken so lightly it's ridiculous.  E.g. listening to music is a major sin, and some of the scholars have said that the one who enjoys it becomes kaffir.
- The punishments of fornication and adultery are so harsh and painful.
- I found myself in the position of Ebu Hurejra who asked Muhammed a.s :

  > 'I'm a young boy and can not afford to get married, also I'm afraid of falling in immorality (Zina)' Muhammed a.s didn't replied till he was asked for the firth or the fourth time and he a.s replied to Ebu H. 'Pen is raised and ink is dried. Whether you leave it or not you have to face your fate (Qadr)
- If our deeds (actions) were decreed (written) on our mother's wombs why should we be questioned, judged and punished for them?
- When Musa a.s argued with Adam blaming him for outcasted us from Jannah, Adam said to him:

  > 'Are you blaiming me for a deed Allah decreed for me 40 years ago before I took action'
- Does free will really exist?  Or is our 'freewill' already programmed in details like, every breath, heartbeat, thoughts, seeing, eating, taking actions
- How can the human race be here today when Adam a.s and Huwa had two children (boys)?  Even if they had other kids (females) which Qur'an doesn't attest to, isn't it crazy that we all are product of incest?  Why is Zina so strictly prohibited and harsh punished if we are all the product of incest?
- What about Muhammed a.s married Aisha at age 6 and consumed marriage at the age of 9?  Does a female hits puberty by that age so we can justify the consuming of marriage?

It makes me wonder if does religion has all the answers?  I don't want to believe it, but I know I'm having crisis of faith.  I'm not able to smile more even though I pray which before I had so much happiness in me.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider to take some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and visiting our [help].

Comment: My question to you is: **What is your question?**. This looks like rhetorical question or a statement which has no question. Be aware that most of what I've read in your post is based on wrong information or misinterpretation on your side. And most of your statements have been covered here on the site.

Comment: Do you call wrong information what Quran states and what Ahadith classified Sahih says .

Comment: I call wrong information what you understand or conclude from them!

Comment: @JoeHoxha The problem is not the ahadith and the verses in the Quran. The problem is how we UNDERSTAND them. As Medi1 said, it looks like your post is based on wrong information or misinterpretation. Instead of saying for example: "I have gained knowledge and this and this is haram/halal and not logic". Ask a question "is the topix xx haram? are there different opionins? is my understanding valid?" If you conclude that you already have knowledge about certain topics, it is useless even to ask about them. Try find them one by one in this page. If you can't find them, ask about them, one by one.

Comment: @Kilise I had opened a chatroom [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49292/how-non-muslims-may-evaluate-islam), but perhaps it didn't ping you.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification; they are *not* intended for answering questions and especially not for argument and debate.

Comment: @G.Bach i missed that. I posted a question, if you like to participate with an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression from your question is that you've gained a superficial and imperfect knowledge of a range of aspects of Islam.  In this case, it's unsurprising you're having doubts; you'd have doubts learning about anything in such a manner.  I encourage you to patiently and systematically go through these issues.

I had some doubts while learning about Islam.  Over time, when I studied individual topics in depth, I usually reached an "oh, that makes sense" moment.  After reaching enough of these moments, when I get confused my attitude is now usually "this doesn't make sense to me at the moment, but I'm sure if I spent the time studying it in detail, I could make sense of it".

Now I don't see myself as having doubts.  Instead there's simply things I don't yet understand because I haven't got around to studying them properly.  (Or I'll just ask Allah when I die.)

(Note: there will be exceptions, as mentioned in [Purpose of verses in the Quran which humans do not understand?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30745/17163)  Also, I don't anticipate Allah would necessarily behave in ways that are comprehensible to humans.)

Things which helped me:

- Writing down my problem, or asking on this site (I have six notes my phone at this very moment).  This way I don't need to keep it in my mind all the time, but I don't feel like I'm just ignoring them.
- [The Response](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/) offers a moderate stance in response to some hardline fatawa: *"difference" (ikhtilaf) was perceived as a sign of God's mercy*.  They recommend understanding and choosing from among the differing scholarly opinions that which you believe is the most accurate.

  > ...so long as an issue produces ikhtilaf among the scholars of Islam, it may not be legally prohibited by Muslims...
  >
  > Ultimately, then, the authors’ response to extremism is to leave Muslims, as intelligent readers, to make their own choices, and to live with the consequences of these.

  I found this helpful for dealing with the "everything is haram problem" (as I've come to call it).