# Is it possible to know everything about the Quran?

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy, quran-translation, imaan

I fear that if I read Quran everyday (With translation) I'll know everything about it, like reading a book. There won't be anything new in it.

So, is it possible that one day I will know everthing about the Quran, and there will be no more use to reading it?

Answer (score 1):

People can certainly memorize the Qur'an (so in that sense they can "know" it all), but even in this case there's [still value in reading it](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38274/17163).  However, according to the Qur'an, it contains parts that only Allah understands:

> It is He who has sent down to you, [O Muhammad], the Book; in it are verses [that are] precise - they are the foundation of the Book - and others unspecific. As for those in whose hearts is deviation [from truth], they will follow that of it which is unspecific, seeking discord and seeking an interpretation [suitable to them]. **And no one knows its [true] interpretation except Allah.** But those firm in knowledge say, "We believe in it. All [of it] is from our Lord." And no one will be reminded except those of understanding.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 3:7](https://quran.com/3/7)</sub>

One example which might never be understood by man is:

> Alif, Lam, Meem, Sad.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 7:1](https://quran.com/7/1)</sub>

One tafsir writes:

> Alif Lām Mīm Sād God knows best what He means by these letters.
>   <sub>[Tafsir al-Jalalayn](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=7&tAyahNo=1&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)</sub>

See also:  [Purpose of verses in the Quran which humans do not understand?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30745/17163)